# ADC0820 and piezo drum pad

Tags: arduino, adc, piezo

Bit of a newb with electronics, so if this question has an obvious answer, please excuse me.

I am trying to attach an electronic drum pad to the Vin input of an [ADC0820](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/ADC0820.pdf) flash ADC. I am powering it with 5 V and using a 3.3 V reference voltage (the voltage ref is a differential input on this IC, with a V<sub>REF</sub>- of 0 V.) When I attach a 10 k pot to the ADC V<sub>IN</sub> input, everything works as expected.

Here's the thing that's confusing me: when I hook up a scope and read the drum pad when it's not attached to the ADC, it reads at 0 V when not being hit. However, when I attach it to the V<sub>IN</sub> input this level rises to 0.1 V and causes the ADC to read above 0. It seems the V<sub>IN</sub> pin is charged from the V<sub>REF</sub>+ pin and this is being sent back down the drum pad. I have confirmed this by connecting a pot to the V<sub>REF</sub>+ pin and turning it up and down - the charge leaving the V<sub>IN</sub> pin changes! This doesn't happen when I experiment with different ADC chips. Why is it happening here?

Comment: Exactly what other ADCs have you tried? Look up their data sheets - how is the ADC0820 input structure different from them?

Comment: I've tried the ADC0804, MCP3008 and a bunch of atmels. Not seeing a difference in the literature that is causing me to twig on to anything

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a raw piezo input, its output is a charge rather than a voltage.  It is rather like a capacitor which is being charged and discharged by the flexing of the sensor.  Your input to your ADC is basically floating, attached to a capacitor when the drum is quiet.  When you put the scope on it, the probe impedance discharges the piezo sensor.  You will need a resistor to ground sufficient to discharge the leakage current on the input of the ADC, which is spec'd as +/- 3uA.  You may want a resistor divider anyway between ground and Vref so that your ADC can see negative swings.  Note that a big hit will generate a voltage exceeding your Vcc, so you may also need some protection.

Comment: @DanTurner: John's answer looks correct but we recommend that you wait a day or too before accepting so that you don't deter other good answers as your question ripples around the globe - especially in this case as you haven't tried it out! You can un-accept for a while and re-accept later. I hope that's OK, John.